# Multidimensional array of multi checkbox group values jQuery post array AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. I want to add/remove check-box values to an array and pass to a JavaScript ajax call. I want to be able to pass all sort array to on array for the ajax call. Each time a checkbox is changed it updates the array, which in turn should update the array that's passed to ajax.

```
<input class='sort1' type='checkbox' value='' name='sort1' />
<input class='sort1' type='checkbox' value='' name='sort1' />
<input class='sort1' type='checkbox' value='' name='sort1' />

<input class='sort2' type='checkbox' value='' name='sort2' />
<input class='sort2' type='checkbox' value='' name='sort2' />

<input class='sort3' type='checkbox' value='' name='sort3' />
<input class='sort3' type='checkbox' value='' name='sort3' />
<input class='sort3' type='checkbox' value='' name='sort3' />
<input class='sort3' type='checkbox' value='' name='sort3' />


var arr_sort = {}
var arr_sort1 = {};
var arr_sort2 = {};
var arr_sort3 = {};

    $(".sort1").delegate("input[type='checkbox']", 'change', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.prop('checked')) {
            arr_sort1[$this.attr('name')] = $this.val();
        } else {
            delete arr_sort1[$this.attr('name')];
        }

        ajax_call();

    });

$(".sort2").delegate("input[type='checkbox']", 'change', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.prop('checked')) {
            arr_sort2[$this.attr('name')] = $this.val();
        } else {
            delete arr_sort2[$this.attr('name')];
        }

        ajax_call();

    });

$(".sort3").delegate("input[type='checkbox']", 'change', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.prop('checked')) {
            arr_sort3[$this.attr('name')] = $this.val();
        } else {
            delete arr_sort3[$this.attr('name')];
        }

        ajax_call();

    });

function ajax_call(){

    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "file.php",
         data: { thisaction: thisaction, sort: arr_sort},
         success: function(data){ 
             $("#results").html(data);
            }
        }); 

}
```

i could maybe do this, but I want to pass the array to php to handle especially if there are more check-box groups added.

Outcome

```
array (
   "sort1" => array("1","2","3"),
   "sort2" => array("this","that"),
   "sort3" => array("other","ok")
)

or

array (
   "sort1" => array("1","2","3"),
   "sort2" => array("this")
   "sort3" => array()
)
```

Comment: Could you make the question more specific? I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/XS48K/**

**Notes:**

- **Each `name` needs to be unique.**  This is good form anyway.  I named them box# but you should use more appropriate names that describe what they are.
- **Use `data` attribute to group objects.**  This is the semantic way to do this.
- **Your `input`s should be in a `form` tag with an `id`.**  This helps you use jQuery selectors to get the objects that you want.
- **I erased the `value` attribute.**  You can put a value back in if you'd like to.  I just would prefer not see the value attribute in there.
- **You should store all of them in an object or array.**  This is so you can manage ALL of the checked states in one place.

Comment: @nnnnnn, you need to know that **delete** do not remove an element from an array it will only set it as undefined, so you can get something like `group1:{box1:undefined, box2:undefined, box3:undefined }`

Comment: get this error$this.prop is not a function
[Break On This Error] if ($this.prop('checked')) {

Comment: .prop() was introduced only in jQuery 1.6

Comment: @atma Tested in modern browswers the property was removed.  I'm not sure what the full browser range is.

Comment: @madphp Unless you have some reason to not upgrade, you really ought to upgrade jQuery versions.

Comment: [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) is the jQuery _method_, not the native browser _property_. So it supported by >=IE6, Safari >=3, FF >=2 and all Chrome versions. What the version of your jQuery?

Comment: But you still can use `$this.is(':checked')`, this working in earlier (<1.6) versions of jQuery

Comment: @atma I was referring to the **delete** statement.  I do not get undefined, I get that property no longer exists in FF 5|6, latest Chrome.

Comment: This is for the Array() object or *[]*. It's just a warning for @madphp. Some useful functions found [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/)